# Install Ubuntu Server on unused unformated partition (or on free space) - DUAL Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, lvm

**Context:**
 - 1 SSD
 - Secure boot UEFI
 - 50 GB space

I want to install Ubuntu Server on a system that has a newly created "shrunk" space from Windows 10. I have tried both partitioned and by setting it up as a "Simple Drive" without any file system.

**When using "free space" (without any partition):**
When I am using the Ubuntu Server Installer the free space is visible in the installer but I can not choose any option to install on it.

**When set up as a partition without any file system**
I can choose the drive under manual but not sure how to continue the installation after that. I can apparently format it and set up RAID or LVM but the installation instructions I find is not for the "manual" mode. Only for using the whole disk. If I choose manual, should I use LVM on partition 5?

Please advice =)

Comment: It’s a bit unusual to install Ubuntu Server alongside W10. A serious server application would normally run 24/7, in which case why have Windows on there at all. If you are just looking to just play around with the server I’d recommend installing virtualbox and installing it as a VM. In fact you can run a VM server as a prototype perfectly well. (Subject to Windows crashing or rebooting when it feels like it)

Comment: That is not an option, my goal is as above mentioned. If I use Ubuntu Desktop I know that  I can use the GUI at installation to utilize the space, but I can't see why this shouldn't be possible with Ubuntu Server.

Comment: I ended up creating a logical volume with a swap disk and a disk for root in that view. Then I had to mark the Volume Group disk as bootable to be able to continue with the installation.

Not sure if correct or not, but it got me forward for now. If someone knows a better solution, please add it here.